# Django Custom Form Validation not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to get some custom form validation working on Django but its not currently working.

```
class PostCodeForm (forms.Form):
    pcode = forms.CharField()

    def clean_pcode(self):
        permitted = {'a','b','c','d'}
        pcode = self.cleaned_data['pcode']
        if not str(permitted) in pcode:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Apologies, but surrey Spice does not currently deliver to you postcode.")
        return pcode
```

The end goal is that anything not in that tuple should not be permitted and should return the validation error. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: is `permitted` a set of complete valid postcodes or is it a set of individual characters that the postcode must be made of?

Comment: Why don't you use something like [this](http://codeinthehole.com/tips/validating-international-postcodes-in-django/) that has been already tested, is more general and works

Comment: From the name Surrey Spice, I'm guessing that permitted is a set of postcode districts like `{'GU1', 'GU2', ...}`, and the OP wants `pcode` to be in one of those districts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison is backwards.

You're checking `permitted in pcode`, but you want `pcode in permitted` instead.

Comment: This is better, but my guess is that `permitted` is list of postcode districts like 'GU1', so they'll want the check to be something like `pcode[:-3] in permitted`.

Comment: May be a different question, but how would I get this to ignore case?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but I will take a shot. Also you are using a dictionary for permitted, why is that? A list is more suitable.

If pcode is just a singel value then you would do soemthing like:

```
if pcode not in permitted:
    #stuff
```

If pcode is a list and you would like to check if the values in pcode are in permitted then you would do:

```
if not set(pcode).issubset(permitted):
   #stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Out of interest what does set and issubset do?

Comment: Actually, this only works if I set the tuple as a single character, e.g. 'a' but not its something like an actual postcode 'SW10 5LX' (made up postcode)

Comment: It works for everything. 

Can you please post your complete code? What is pcode now? A dictionary or a single value? How does permitted look exactly? 

Unless you are not more specific we can't help you...